# Android UI test Fingerprint with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-fingerprint-api

I have an Android fingerprint implementation working and I was looking to add UI tests with Espresso. One problem I can't find a solution to is how to emulate the scanning of a finger. There is an adb command
`adb -e emu finger touch` which should work on emulators.

Any idea on how to integrate something like that with Espresso?

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution, have you found something?

Comment: Did you come up with anything for this?

Comment: Nope, we ended up creating a mocked version of our fingerprint implementation allowing us to test the flow

Comment: @QuirijnGB can you post an example of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329515/fingerprint-reader-espresso-test) sending to an emulator is possible:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb -e emu finger touch 1")
```

I expect, though can't show any working, that faking a fingerprint on a real device would require some special kind of security magic.

*Edit*: this doesn't work from *within* espresso tests.

Comment: You can use Kaspresso to do this though. We use their ADB server to send adb commands and normal commands.


https://github.com/KasperskyLab/Kaspresso


    val result = adbServer.performAdb("-e emu finger touch 1")
    assert(result[0].contains("exitCode=0, message=OK"))