# Fingerprint reader espresso test

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-fingerprint-api

I am trying to make espresso test for fingerprint reading. It is possible for emulator test with such

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb -e emu finger touch 1");`

However this same code is not working on real devices.
What is the way to do fingerprint reader on espresso test for real devices?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but, as far as I know, this is not possible with real devices.